# OpenSSL : How do I add a AIA extension to a certificate

Tags: openssl

I'm currently using a self-signed CA certificate in a development environment and I generate certificates signed by this CA.

I want to add an AIA extension to any new certificates I generate with the location of this CA cert.

How do I do this? Do I need to add something to my openssl.cnf config file when creating a new certificate?

Comment: It depends first on whether you are using `openssl x509 -req -CA/CAkey` or `openssl ca` and if the latter with what options and configuration. All these cases are specified in the respective man pages, although the _data_ for extensions is specified in the man page for x509v3_config ('v3' being the version that defined extensions). All extension data must be in some file (except `req` in 1.1.1, not relevant here) but _which_ file -- and whether it is even a permanent file -- can vary depending on your platform and environment, and options.